# falla función System.Math.Round(2429402.5) de NET y redondea hacia abajo con 2429402.0

Tags: c#, redondeo

alguien por favor podría explicarme por que razón la función Math.Round de .NET falla al ejecutar `System.Math.Round(2429402.5)`, no redondea hacia arriba, el resultado es `2429402.0` y no `2429403.0`.

No logro saber si es un error del framework o es el número.

[image: Muestra ejecución System.Math.Round(2429402.5)]

Comment: Algún colega que le haya pasado

Comment: round, ceil, floor son los metodos que necesitas y estos existen tambien  en java, javascript, y debe haber similares en otros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto ocurre tal como dice la documentación

> Valor de retorno
>   Tipo: System.Double
>   El número entero más cercano a . Si el componente fraccional de una está a medio camino entre dos números enteros, uno de los cuales es par y el otro impar, entonces se devuelve el número par. Tenga en cuenta que este método devuelve un doble en lugar de un tipo entero.

Tu resultado se encuentra entre `2429402` y `2429403`, la documentación dice que si se encuentra entre un numero par o impar, devuelve el par.

[Documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

El comportamiento es acorde con la documentacion de la funcion [Math.Round(Decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/3s2d3xkk(v=vs.110).aspx). Para el comportamiento que requieres lo mas recomendable es utilizar [Math.Round(Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms131275(v=vs.110).aspx) ya que puedes indicar la cantidad de decimales y como se va a comportar el redonde

```
Console.WriteLine("AwayFromZero");
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(2429402.4, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(2429402.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(2429402.6, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("ToEven");
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(2429402.4, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(2429402.5, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(2429402.6, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
```

Resultado

```
AwayFromZero
2429402
2429403
2429403

ToEven
2429402
2429402
2429403
```

Comment: Mil gracias Byron, creo que así si es hermano. saludos!!!!!

Comment: @GeovannyRios si has comprobado que esta respuesta te ha resuelto el problema, recuerda aceptar esta pregunta pulsando sobre el tick debajo del recuento de votos

Comment: Listo, mil gracias, esta fue la solución al error en producción del error presentado en la plataforma, la función que se adapta mejor es System.Math.Round(2429402.4, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), saludos.

Answer (score 2):

La función que más se adapta a mi necesidad fue la siguiente:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(2429402.6, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

esta función me permite redondear el numero hacia arriba y hacia abajo sin ningún problema con los tipos de datos, gracias a todos.

Comment: Buena!! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Es que `Math.Round` busca el más próximo no el mas grande, para eso debes usar  `Math.Ceiling`

`Math.Ceilin` te devolverá el entero mayor siguiente al numero que le pases por parámetro, también existe otra función `Math.Floor` que hace exactamente lo contrario a `Ceiling`.

ejemplos :

```
Console.WriteLine("Round: " + System.Math.Round(2429402.5));
Console.WriteLine("Floor: " + System.Math.Floor(2429402.5));
Console.WriteLine("Ceiling: " + System.Math.Ceiling(2429402.5));
```

Salida del programa:

> Round: 2429402
>   Floor: 2429402
>   Ceiling: 2429403

Referencias:

- [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Math.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/1cz5da1c(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hola Alan, aunque si tengo este número System.Math.Ceiling(2429402.3) me lo sube a 2429403.0 y debería bajármelo a 2429402.0, creo que tengo que crear una nueva función.. mil gracias saludos..

Comment: fíjate la respuesta de @sioesi, la mía es para evitar esto y si siempre queires obtener el mayor utiliza las otras funciones Como Ceiling y Floor  y no round.

Comment: Perfecto gracias Alan